# page sizing & handling on acrobar pro dc via vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, printing, acrobat

I have managed convert a list of images onto pdf, then gathered them in a single file and then print them as multiple pages 10 columns x 14 rows so I can print in a single sheet 140 original images.
All of these with sendkeys method which was absolutely madness and frustrating but at the end it works pretty fine, the only handicap is that I have to do this almost everyday and once I run the sendkeys macro I can't do nothing with my computer until it ends which could probably be hours

I'm trying to do this in a less "messy" way

I have managed to convert the images in pdf easely with this code I modified from a search on internet (just in case someone find it usefull for him/her)

```
Sub png_to_pdf()
Dim Acroapp As New Acrobat.Acroapp
Dim pddoc As New Acrobat.AcroPDDoc

Set Acroapp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set pddoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.pddoc")

aux_pngtopdf "F:\ES-VAL\PURCH-U\CARLOS\qr", pddoc
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub aux_pngtopdf(ByVal xFolderName As String, ByVal pddoc As Object)
Dim xFileSystemObject As Object
Dim xFolder As Object
Dim xSubFolder As Object
Dim xFile As Object
Dim xfilepdf As String

Set xFileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set xFolder = xFileSystemObject.GetFolder(xFolderName)
        

        
For Each xFile In xFolder.Files
    If Right(xFile, 3) = "png" And Application.CountIf(Columns(10), Mid(xFolderName, 29, 9)) = 0 And Application.CountIf(Columns(11), Mid(xFolderName, 29, 9)) = 0 Then

        pddoc.Open xFile
        
        xfilepdf = Left(xFile, Len(xFile) - 3) & "pdf"
                
        pddoc.Save PDSaveFull, xfilepdf

            
    End If
Next xFile

For Each xSubFolder In xFolder.subfolders
    If Len(xSubFolder) < 250 Then
        aux_pngtopdf xSubFolder.Path, pddoc
    End If
Next xSubFolder
    
Set xFile = Nothing
Set xFolder = Nothing
Set xFileSystemObject = Nothing
            
End Sub
```

I'm changing the code I found (I don't really remember if here or if in any other site) to merge all the pdf into a single one and it seems it would be fine

```
Sub merge_pdf()

Const DestFile As String = "MergedFile.pdf" ' <-- change to suit

Dim MyPath As String, MyFiles As String
Dim a() As String, i As Long, f As String
Dim j As Integer

j = 4
   
 ' Choose the folder or just replace that part by: MyPath = Range("E3")
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
     '.InitialFileName = "C:\Temp\"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = False Then Exit Sub
    MyPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\" & Cells(j, 3).Value
    DoEvents
End With

  ' Populate the array a() by PDF file names
If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
ReDim a(1 To 2 ^ 14)
f = Dir(MyPath & "*.pdf")
While Len(f)
    If StrComp(f, DestFile, vbTextCompare) Then
        i = i + 1
        a(i) = f
    End If
    f = Dir()
Wend

' Merge PDFs
If i Then
    ReDim Preserve a(1 To i)
    MyFiles = Join(a, ",")
    Application.StatusBar = "Merging, please wait ..."
    Call aux_MergePDFs(MyPath, MyFiles, DestFile)
    Application.StatusBar = False
Else
    MsgBox "No PDF files found in" & vbLf & MyPath, vbExclamation, "Canceled"
End If

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub aux_MergePDFs(MyPath As String, MyFiles As String, Optional DestFile As String = "MergedFile.pdf")


Dim a As Variant, i As Long, n As Long, ni As Long, p As String
Dim Acroapp As New Acrobat.Acroapp, PartDocs() As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc

If Right(MyPath, 1) = "\" Then p = MyPath Else p = MyPath & "\"
a = Split(MyFiles, ",")
ReDim PartDocs(0 To UBound(a))

On Error GoTo exit_
If Len(Dir(p & DestFile)) Then Kill p & DestFile
For i = 0 To UBound(a)
    ' Check PDF file presence
    If Dir(p & Trim(a(i))) = "" Then
        MsgBox "File not found" & vbLf & p & a(i), vbExclamation, "Canceled"
        Exit For
    End If
    ' Open PDF document
    Set PartDocs(i) = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    PartDocs(i).Open p & Trim(a(i))
    If i Then
        ' Merge PDF to PartDocs(0) document
        ni = PartDocs(i).GetNumPages()
        If Not PartDocs(0).InsertPages(n - 1, PartDocs(i), 0, ni, True) Then
            MsgBox "Cannot insert pages of" & vbLf & p & a(i), vbExclamation, "Canceled"
        End If
        ' Calc the number of pages in the merged document
        n = n + ni
        ' Release the memory
        PartDocs(i).Close
        Set PartDocs(i) = Nothing
    Else
        ' Calc the number of pages in PartDocs(0) document
        n = PartDocs(0).GetNumPages()
    End If
Next

If i > UBound(a) Then
    ' Save the merged document to DestFile
    If Not PartDocs(0).Save(PDSaveFull, p & DestFile) Then
        MsgBox "Cannot save the resulting document" & vbLf & p & DestFile, vbExclamation, "Canceled"
    End If
End If

exit_:

' Inform about error/success
If Err Then
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error #" & Err.Number
ElseIf i > UBound(a) Then
    MsgBox "The resulting file is created:" & vbLf & p & DestFile, vbInformation, "Done"
End If

' Quit Acrobat application
Acroapp.Exit
Set Acroapp = Nothing

End Sub
```

But I don't have any clue on how to print several pages of the pdf into a single one. Not interested in only 16 pages per sheet (since the images I try to print are QR codes 12mmx12mm so it fits pretty fine 140 of them in a single sheet) which could be more or less easy if you set adobe pdf as your default printer and setup it to print 16 pages per sheet (I also found part of a code that could fit to this purpose)

Any clue will be apreciated

Thanks

Comment: Don't really know if I understand you correctly. To merging all the images in a single pdf is not the problem, each resulting page is 50x50 pixel so it can be place in 10 columns and 14 rows without changing nothing. The problem is to print 140 pages in a single sheet, I cannot find nobody asking for this on adobe's or excel's forum so I have no idea where to start to coding this. It is a very simple task if you have to do it manually. You only have to open the pdf, then ctrl+p, select multiple ->10 columns x 14 rows and print with adobe pdf printer

Comment: the fact is that I own a license for acrobat dc pro which allows me to do it perfectly manually, so I thought that there should be a way to refer to this on vba by using the proper reference library/command/property. Anyway if the only way is to refer to external websites or so I have a workaround using sendkeys method, it is not the most elegant options and seems a kind of a stupid way to solve this problem but if it works it's not stupid

Comment: agree with you about how excel manage the images. Also when you insert 50x50 pixel images in word it becomes blurry wich is not an option when you are managing QR codes. Anyway thanks for your suggestion, seems sendkeys are in fact the best option :|